# Поиск по словарю python

Tags: python, python-2.7, словари

Здравствуйте!

Есть у меня некий словарь, где много больше элементов чем в примере:

```
a = { 'hosts': [{u'available': u'0',
             u'disable_until': u'0',
             u'error': u'',
             u'errors_from': u'0',
             u'groups': [{u'groupid': u'361'}],
             u'host': u'my.hostname.local',
             u'hostid': u'144844',
             u'interfaces': {u'302972': {u'dns': u'my.hostname.local',
                                         u'hostid': u'144844',
                                         u'interfaceid': u'302972',
                                         u'ip': u'1.1.1.1',
                                         u'main': u'1',
                                         u'port': u'161',
                                         u'type': u'2',
                                         u'useip': u'1'}},
             u'ipmi_authtype': u'-1',
             u'ipmi_available': u'0',
             u'ipmi_disable_until': u'0',
             u'ipmi_error': u'',
             u'ipmi_errors_from': u'0',
             u'ipmi_password': u'',
             u'ipmi_privilege': u'2',
             u'ipmi_username': u'',
             u'jmx_available': u'0',
             u'jmx_disable_until': u'0',
             u'jmx_error': u'',
             u'jmx_errors_from': u'0',
             u'lastaccess': u'0',
             u'maintenance_from': u'0',
             u'maintenance_status': u'0',
             u'maintenance_type': u'0',
             u'maintenanceid': u'0',
             u'maintenances': [],
             u'proxy_hostid': u'11223',
             u'snmp_available': u'2',
             u'snmp_disable_until': u'0',
             u'snmp_errors_from': u'0',
             u'status': u'0'}] }
```

В добавок ко всему, как вы наверно заметили, он в юникоде. Элементов у `u'interfaces'` может быть как один, так и сотни. Собсно вопросы:

1. Как для каждого элемента сделать `.encode("utf-8")` чтоб избавиться от `u'` и в дальнейшем удобнее работать с этим словарём?
2. Как-то можно в python производить удобный поиск по словарю без миллионов вложенных `for key, value in ...` ? Конкретно из всего этого безобразия мне нужно получить `b = {"my.hostname.local" : {"ip" : "1.1.1.1"}}` где `my.hostname.local` соответствует полю `u'host'`, а `ip` нужно взять из того `u'interfaces'`, в котором есть `u'type': u'2'` . Я понимаю как это сделать с помощью 100500 циклов for, но это же ужасно и невероятно неудобно. Есть ли какой-то более хороший и быстрый способ?

Comment: Как вы представляете процесс поиска? что вы вводите и что ожидаете получить? пример ввода и вывода пожалуйста. Особенно для этого: а ip нужно взять из того u'interfaces', в котором есть u'type': u'2'
Вам нужен общий метод поиска или только для получения каких-то конкретных данных?

Comment: @Max , здравствуйте. Для начала мне нужно всё это избавить от юникода, потому что я даже с помощью `for` не могу решить проблему как думал раньше. Процесс поиска банален: функция `a.find('ip')` которая бы вывела все ключи `ip` с их значением и, возможно, с "путём" по которым их можно найти. Это же элементарно, почему этого ещё никто не сделал? То что в итоге мне нужно получить я написАл выше, однако смею полагать, что в будущем мне понадобится искать что-то ещё в этом словаре.

Comment: @user231551, вы можете выложить более сложный пример (можно в виде ссылки на JSON файл или в виде Python кода как у вас в вопросе)? `host` - всегда один или их может быть много? `interfaces` - всегда указаны в виде словаря или могут быть как список?

Comment: @MaxU `hosts` всегда один. Он всегда содержит один `list`, состоящий из множества словарей, в каждом из которым может быть только один ключ `interfaces` но в нём может быть множество `int` ключей значения которых могут отличаться. Простите если слишком сложно объясняю.

Comment: @user231551, в этом единственном списке (list) - всегда только один элемен (host) или их может быть несколько?

Comment: @user231551, кажется понял - `состоящий из множества словарей` - т.е. хостов может быть много...

Comment: @MaxU ext. example: http://pastebin.com/RyLFw05E

Comment: @MaxU пардон, в прошлом примере ошибка в `host` ключах, а править свои комменты я не могу, вот новый пример: http://pastebin.com/BsYZGbzR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

def get_ip(dct):
    if isinstance(dct, dict):
        if 'type' in dct and 'ip' in dct and 'dns' in dct and dct['type'] == '2':
            return {dct['dns']: {'ip':dct['ip']}}
    return pd.np.nan


In [113]: (pd.DataFrame(a['hosts'])
     ...:    .interfaces
     ...:    .apply(pd.Series)
     ...:    .applymap(get_ip)
     ...:    .apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
     ...:    .tolist()
     ...: )
     ...:
Out[113]:
[{'my.hostname.local': {'ip': '1.1.1.1'}},
 {'my01.hostname.local': {'ip': '1.1.1.1'}},
 {'my13.hostname.local': {'ip': '1.1.1.1'}}]
```

PS в качестве `hostname` я использовал `dns` из `interfaces`

Setup:

```
a = { 'hosts': [{u'available': u'0',
             u'disable_until': u'0',
             u'error': u'',
             u'errors_from': u'0',
             u'groups': [{u'groupid': u'361'}],
             u'host': u'my.hostname.local',
             u'hostid': u'144844',
             u'interfaces': {u'302972': {u'dns': u'my.hostname.local',
                                         u'hostid': u'144844',
                                         u'interfaceid': u'302972',
                                         u'ip': u'1.1.1.1',
                                         u'main': u'1',
                                         u'port': u'161',
                                         u'type': u'2',
                                         u'useip': u'1'}},
             u'ipmi_authtype': u'-1',
             u'ipmi_available': u'0',
             u'ipmi_disable_until': u'0',
             u'ipmi_error': u'',
             u'ipmi_errors_from': u'0',
             u'ipmi_password': u'',
             u'ipmi_privilege': u'2',
             u'ipmi_username': u'',
             u'jmx_available': u'0',
             u'jmx_disable_until': u'0',
             u'jmx_error': u'',
             u'jmx_errors_from': u'0',
             u'lastaccess': u'0',
             u'maintenance_from': u'0',
             u'maintenance_status': u'0',
             u'maintenance_type': u'0',
             u'maintenanceid': u'0',
             u'maintenances': [],
             u'proxy_hostid': u'11223',
             u'snmp_available': u'2',
             u'snmp_disable_until': u'0',
             u'snmp_errors_from': u'0',
             u'status': u'0'},
             {u'available': u'0',
             u'disable_until': u'0',
             u'error': u'',
             u'errors_from': u'0',
             u'groups': [{u'groupid': u'361'}],
             u'host': u'my2.hostname.local',
             u'hostid': u'144844',
             u'interfaces': {u'302973': {u'dns': u'my01.hostname.local',
                                         u'hostid': u'144844',
                                         u'interfaceid': u'302973',
                                         u'ip': u'1.1.1.1',
                                         u'main': u'1',
                                         u'port': u'161',
                                         u'type': u'2',
                                         u'useip': u'1'},
                             u'321123': {u'dns': u'my02.hostname.local',
                                         u'hostid': u'321',
                                         u'interfaceid': u'321312',
                                         u'ip': u'2.2.2.2',
                                         u'type': u'3',
                                         u'useip': u'1'},
                             u'675675': {u'dns': u'my03.hostname.local',
                                         u'hostid': u'566454',
                                         u'interfaceid': u'8987798',
                                         u'ip': u'3.3.3.3',
                                         u'type': u'1',
                                         u'useip': u'1'}},
             u'ipmi_authtype': u'-1',
             u'ipmi_available': u'0',
             u'ipmi_disable_until': u'0',
             u'ipmi_error': u'',
             u'ipmi_errors_from': u'0',
             u'ipmi_password': u'',
             u'ipmi_privilege': u'2',
             u'ipmi_username': u'',
             u'jmx_available': u'0',
             u'jmx_disable_until': u'0',
             u'jmx_error': u'',
             u'jmx_errors_from': u'0',
             u'lastaccess': u'0',
             u'maintenance_from': u'0',
             u'maintenance_status': u'0',
             u'maintenance_type': u'0',
             u'maintenanceid': u'0',
             u'maintenances': [],
             u'proxy_hostid': u'11223',
             u'snmp_available': u'2',
             u'snmp_disable_until': u'0',
             u'snmp_errors_from': u'0',
             u'status': u'0'},
             {u'available': u'0',
             u'disable_until': u'0',
             u'error': u'',
             u'errors_from': u'0',
             u'groups': [{u'groupid': u'361'}],
             u'host': u'my3.hostname.local',
             u'hostid': u'144844',
             u'interfaces': {u'402972': {u'dns': u'my13.hostname.local',
                                         u'hostid': u'144844',
                                         u'interfaceid': u'402972',
                                         u'ip': u'1.1.1.1',
                                         u'main': u'1',
                                         u'port': u'161',
                                         u'type': u'2',
                                         u'useip': u'1'},
                             u'421123': {u'dns': u'my12.hostname.local',
                                         u'hostid': u'321',
                                         u'interfaceid': u'421312',
                                         u'ip': u'2.2.2.2',
                                         u'type': u'3',
                                         u'useip': u'1'},
                             u'475675': {u'dns': u'my13.hostname.local',
                                         u'hostid': u'566454',
                                         u'interfaceid': u'8987798',
                                         u'ip': u'3.3.3.3',
                                         u'type': u'1',
                                         u'useip': u'1'}},
             u'ipmi_authtype': u'-1',
             u'ipmi_available': u'0',
             u'ipmi_disable_until': u'0',
             u'ipmi_error': u'',
             u'ipmi_errors_from': u'0',
             u'ipmi_password': u'',
             u'ipmi_privilege': u'2',
             u'ipmi_username': u'',
             u'jmx_available': u'0',
             u'jmx_disable_until': u'0',
             u'jmx_error': u'',
             u'jmx_errors_from': u'0',
             u'lastaccess': u'0',
             u'maintenance_from': u'0',
             u'maintenance_status': u'0',
             u'maintenance_type': u'0',
             u'maintenanceid': u'0',
             u'maintenances': [],
             u'proxy_hostid': u'11223',
             u'snmp_available': u'2',
             u'snmp_disable_until': u'0',
             u'snmp_errors_from': u'0',
             u'status': u'0'}] }
```

Comment: Хм, хороший пакет, не знал о таком (`pandas`). А если вместо `dns` подставлять `host` , как будет?

Comment: А, впрочем, не заморачивайтесь, и так пойдёт. Посмотрю что может `pandas` на досуге и переделаю как нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: @user231551, решение могло бы быть на порядок проще если бы `interfaces` был в виде списка словарей, например: http://pastebin.com/hZRDYy3Q

Answer (score 0):

Для ясности, вот пример кода, как используя for-циклы получить искомые данные:

```
>>> [{interface['dns'].encode(): {'ip': interface['ip'].encode()}}
...  for host in a['hosts']
...  for interface in host['interfaces'].itervalues()
...  if interface['type'] == '2']
[{'my.hostname.local': {'ip': '1.1.1.1'}},
 {'my01.hostname.local': {'ip': '1.1.1.1'}},
 {'my13.hostname.local': {'ip': '1.1.1.1'}}]
```

Код предполагает, что `inteface['dns']` не содержит [интернационализованных доменных имён](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN) (что результат всегда в ascii (`sys.getdefaultencoding()`) представим).

`u''` это текстовое представление unicode объекта в Питоне (как он в исходном коде выглядит). Текстовые данные не следует в байты превращать (что `.encode('utf-8')` делает), если это не является необходимым (например, какое-нибудь API принимает только байты). Если вы будете использовать байты, чтобы представить текст, то возможно смешать текст, представленный в разных кодировках и получить мусор на выходе, не заметив этого. Чтобы исключить подобный источник ошибок, в Питоне 3 `str` аналогичен `unicode` типу из Питона 2.

Код в примере выше работает, потому что в Питоне 2, `str` объект, содержащий данные в ascii диапазоне (`sys.getdefaultencoding()`) может с `unicode` работать, когда необходимо:

```
>>> u'1' == '1'
True
>>> u'1' in {u'1': 'a'}
True
>>> '1' in {u'1': 'a'}
True
>>> {u'1': 'a'}[u'1']
'a'
>>> {u'1': 'a'}['1']
'a'
```

Comment: Ага, я именно так и сделал, но мой вариант побольше чем Ваш: http://pastebin.com/h7A2Td7E . С превеликим удовольствием использовал бы python3 чтоб не смущали дурацкие `u'`, но увы нет тех. возможности. Спасибо за Ваш вариант! P.S. У вас много репутации, объявите конкурс на самую короткую запись кода :)

Comment: @user231551: 1- ваш код, а также конкретные проблемы с ним, лучше в самом вопросе приводить, чтобы точно определить что вы хотите найти и чем текущий подход не устраивает (если устраивает, то в качестве [собственного ответа можете опубликовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).  2- Код в моём ответе самый прямолинейным (в лоб) и читаемый (насколько у меня получилось). Краткость—это плохой критерий (вы можете создать новый вопрос с меткой [tag:соревнование], но это будет уже другой вопрос, другие критерии оценки кода). Посмотрите в описании метки о правилах для таких вопросов.

Comment: Эм-м, на счёт конкурса - это юмор был такой, ну знаете, "ха-ха :)" и т.п. свой "ответ" я доделал почти одновременно с @MaxU и Вами поэтому и не опубликовал его. В общем-то я теме я написал, что в принципе знаю как это решить, но мне это не очень нравится. Если не ошибаюсь, pep8 в случаях с трёхэтажными вложенными циклами как раз придерживается политики "краткости". Но всё равно спасибо.